# Резиновая плитка из картинок

Tags: html, css

!Здраствуйте. Подскажите, как можно сделать вот такую мини-галерею из картинок резиновой. С шириной все в порядке, а высоту никак не задать в процентах. Заранее спасибо) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: резиновый, это вам на завод красный треугольник :) не понятно что Вам надо :)

Comment: Уменьшается окно, уменьшаются картинки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Высота в % - небольшой хак с помощью

```
height: 0
padding-bottom: 100%
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul,
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    font-size: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}

li .bl-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

li .bl-img img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-img">
    <li>
        <div class="bl-img"><img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt=""></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bl-img"><img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt=""></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bl-img"><img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt=""></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bl-img"><img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt=""></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически высоту можно задать в процентах, но для этого у родительского блока должна быть фиксированная высота. Возможно, вам подойдут единицы измерения vh. `height: 80vh;` например, будет означать высоту в 80% от общей высоты экрана, тем самым, при изменении высоты экрана, блок всегда будет занимать 80% высоты всей страницы